# How to link winform buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've wrote code in c++ and c# but only using the console. Now I want to create a little app. I've made the UI:
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1cCf.jpg)

So this is the UI. And the idea behind this is that this app can read from a text file with this information (firstName, lastName, age and the status) separated by comas. The user can also add info here, and the information will be written in the same text file. But this is the thing, I don't know how to do this. I've labeled each component, but I don't know how to access them (I mean to take each one and write a code like: firstName + lastName +...you get the idea). Also, I don't know how to code the button. I'm a beginner so I know I'm asking probably a dumb question. I'm not asking for code, just for a guide.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "code the button". Or "write a code like first name etc.". I don't get the idea. You need to explain what you are trying to do. Do you want your program to execute code when you click a button? In that case, go to the form designer where you added your buttons, and double click on the button you want. To change other stuff on your form controls, right lcick on a button or the form and select "Properties" from the context menu.

Comment: I think you need a Winforms tutorial. Here [the results of a simple search](https://www.bing.com/search?q=winforms%20tutorial%20using%20c%23&qs=AS&sk=AS1&pq=winforms%20tutorial&sp=2&sc=8-17&form=BDKTKA&pc=BDT1&shash=&BDParam=0000&mkt=en-US)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info! I have two butttons. When i click the first one(add user) i want a user to be added in the right side(group box). When I click the second one(save file), i want all the info to be saved in a text file. So the I'm strugling with taking the info in the text boxes(firstName, lastName, etc). I don't know how to use this info. Should I create a cs file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio then keep reading :)

Double click on the button to create an event handler for that button.  Same goes for any component you add to the screen.  Then you can execute another method that contains your logic.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { //your code here }
```

Also if you're looking for different events checkout the "properties" of each component, it has a list of all its settings as well as a list of possible events.  To use one of these events, just double click it and it will create one.

Comment: Ok, got it man, thanks! Now I have another q. The code classes for firstname, lastname, should be in a separate class created by me? Or in the button handler?

Answer (score 0):

Write all the business logic (classes, algorithms, repositories) in a library (.net framework or .net core depending on whichever technology you used for your windows forms app).

Then reference (right click on Dependencies -> Add Reference) the library in your Windows Forms project and you can access whatever classes/logic you wrote there.

*Think of the library as a Console App, without the Main class.*

For writing/reading files check System.IO and Streams.